# Oops! All Acros--

Tags: story, cryptic-crosswords

<sup>This puzzle was originally formatted as a PDF; the puzzle PDF is available [on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/10v1nefxaz4m737/2-oops_all_acro.pdf?dl=0). A screenshot of the PDF is available below. This puzzle is an entry in Fortnightly Topic Challenge 46, ["Tales from the Cryptic"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7128/fortnightly-topic-challenge-46-tales-from-the-cryptic).</sup>

This is a sequel to [Not Bluebeard's Castle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/106294/11876), which reveals a certain set of works to be the theme of both itself and this puzzle. No knowledge of the works in question is necessary to solve this puzzle. It is highly recommended (though not necessary) that you solve that puzzle before this one.

---

[image: crossword puzzle page, with a large part of it torn off; both instructions and Down clues are only partially visible]

---

Transcript of instructions and Across clues:

```
Oh no! It looks like part of the page
The two unclued Down entries tell y
normal.

The Across clues each have an extr
clue. The first characters of these
message. The last characters (repl
characters) tell you a location on t
nine letters that should be there sp
discovery, as well as how the hosts

Across
1. Nearly root out replica with right doctor giving
  bonus points (5, 6)
12. Maybe palm off — that's way out of bounds (4)
13. Waterfront crossing dedicated to daughter (4)
14. American entrepreneur is gutted by vindictive
  client (4)
15. Inferior group is expanded 50%, secretly (4)
16. Honor contract of revolutionary peer (4)
18. Most incompetent oligarch is a banger, I hear
  (5)
20. Fast writer composed legible notes (5)
21. Pearl's filming new unit of Illuminati territory
  (5)
23. Polish version mostly unplanned (6)
24. Throws out heel of shoe, airplanes, cans, club,
  &c (6)
25. Tout video recorder components as
  "extraordinary" (5)
26. Fades away, as new malformed idiom (5)
28. White House app created by big loon on the
  inside (5)
32. Fellows praise introduction of "natural
  spirituality", taking off uniform (4)
35. Vegetable is despicable (but acceptable before
  treat, regularly) (4)
38. Reflecting over viewpoint for additional
  contributors (2, 2)
39. Shows respect and declines invite (4)
40. Steel edged program elements elicit inter–
  faces (4)
41. Right to enter Duke's infamous three-wheeler,
  being a third of the way out (5, 6)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nearly complete answer. I'm missing what I think is the last step.

The grid:

> ```
>     E X T R A C R E D I T
>     T R E E M A U R I D U
>     A A M F O R D U S E R
>     T Y P E K E E P S A N
>     A W O R S T S T E N O
>     N A C R E I M P R O V
>     E J E C T S O U T R E
>     W A N E S I G L O O R
>     L E T L A D S O K R A
>     E T A L B O W S A E K
>     A U U I U L A E P E E
>     F I R S T S T R I K E
> ```

The clues:

> 1.  Nearly root out <s>replica</s> with right doctor giving **bonus points** (5, 6)
>          — **EXTRACT** = EXTRAC(t) + R + EDIT
>  12. **Maybe palm** <s>off</s> – that's way out of bounds (4)
>          — **TREE** = (s)TREE(t)
>  13. <s>Waterfront</s> **crossing** dedicated to daughter (4)
>          — **FOR** = FOR + D
>  14. American entrepreneur is gutted by <s>vindictive</s> **client** (4)
>          — **USER** = US + E(ntrepreneu)R
>  15. <s>Inferior</s> **group** is expanded 50%, secretly (4)
>          — **TYPE** = (fif)TY PE(rcent)
>  16. **Honor** <s>contract</s> of revolutionary peer (4)
>          — **KEEP** = PEEK<
>  18. **Most incompetent** <s>oligarch</s> is a banger, I hear (5)
>          — **WORST**, homophone of WURST
>  20. **Fast writer** composed <s>legible</s> notes (5)
>          — **STENO** = NOTES*
>  21. **Pearl's filming** new unit of <s>Illuminati</s> territory (5)
>          — **NACRE** = N + ACRE
>  23. Polish <s>version</s> mostly **unplanned** (6)
>          — **IMPROV** = IMPROV(e)
>  24. **Throws out** heel of shoe, airplanes, cans, club, <s>&c</s> (6)
>          — **EJECTS** = (sho)E + C in JE.TS
>  25. Tout <s>video</s> recorder components as "**extraordinary**" (5)
>          — **OUTRE** = (t)OUT RE(crorder)
>  26. **Fades away**, as new malformed <s>idiom</s> (5)
>          — **WANES** = (AS NEW)*
>  28. **White House** <s>app</s> created by big loon on the inside (5)
>          — **IGLOO** = (b)IG LOO(n)
>  32. **Fellows** praise introduction of "<s>natural</s> spirituality", taking off uniform (4)
>          — **LADS** = LA(u)D + S(prituality)
>  35. **Vegetable** is <s>despicable</s> (but acceptable before treat, regularly) (4)
>          — **OKRA** = OK + (t)R(e)A(t)
>  38. Reflecting over <s>viewpoint</s> for **additional contributors** (2, 2)
>          — **ET AL** = LATE<
>  39. **Shows respect** and **declines** <s>invite</s> (4)
>          — **BOWS** (ddef.)
>  40. **Steel** edged program elements elicit <s>inter–</s> faces (4)
>          — **EPEE** = E(dged) P(rogram) E(lements) E(licit)
>  41. Right to enter Duke's <s>infamous</s> three-wheeler, being **a third of the way out** (5, 6)
>          — **FIRST STRIKE** = R in FI.ST'S + TRIKE

The two unclued down entries ...

> ... at 11 and 17 spell: **Turn over a new leaf**.

The first characters ...

> ... of the extra words, crossed out in the clues above, spell, Row VI & Col IV and VIII. The letters at these positions spell: **R.I.P.** or maybe **rip**.

The last characters ...

> ... of the extra words spell: **After the incomplete –s**. The preamble explicitly mentions characters, not letters. The extra word in 40 across is "inter–", making the last character a dash. The preample also mentions "repl[acing ...] characters". I guess that we need to replace the dash with the message found by the first characters, "RIP", so: **After the incomplete rips**.
>
>  This obviously refers to what would be on the torn off part of the page. An "incomplete rip" is one where the tear goes through a letter. This occurs in nine clues:
>
> ```
>      3.   Worke R ... [TEMP in TEMPO]
>      5.    Bers E rk ... [AMOK]
>      7.   Uncul T ured ... [RUDE]
>      9.    Reve R sed ... [(TRESS + DI)<]
>     19.    Plac E s ... [SETS]
>     28.   We he A r ... [homophone indicator for IDLES?]
>     33.   Inver T ed ... [TUBA<]
>     34.   Strik E ... [SWAT]
>     36. beheade D ... [common indicator; REEK]
> ```

So ...

> ... the capital letter is the one that, in the words of the preample, "should be there". These letters spell out **retreated**.
>
>  This could be "how the hosts [reacted | behaved | ...].

Is this the end?

> Hm. I don't know. There's still the question how things could be put back to normal, as Gareth sugests, by "turning over a new leaf". And I don't quite see what the "discovery" mentioned in the preamble might be.

Thanks to ...

> ... Gareth for corrections, observations and discussion and to Deusovi for the hints and, of course, for a super puzzle.

Comment: I am stuck in essentially the same place. I hadn't thought of taking rot13(jbeqf va gur tevq) to be incomplete, which is a clever idea but seems to me not to work because rot13(jr fcrpvsvpnyyl arrq vapbzcyrgr _f_f). There seems to be only _one_ actual incomplete S on the page, in the word rot13(Orefrex) or something with that as prefix, but I don't see anything useful to do with that. Or it could be an rot13(vapbzcyrgr FF) as e.g. in rot13(gur gvgyr vs vg fnlf NPEBFF engure guna NPEBFGVP) but this all feels rather underconstrained.

Comment: Also, what you have as rot13(NYRR) is surely actually rot13(NXRR) because that is a rot13(_fbnc_oreel).

Comment: I also suspect that rot13(QRFFREG) might actually be rot13(QVFFREG) with the torn-off word being rot13(ERIRNY) but of course there might be some homophony going on. [EDITED because I had an entirely wrong word in there.]

Comment: I have the same confusion as you about 40a, by the way. I _suspect_ it's an error, with rot13("vagresnprf" obgu qryrgrq naq abg).

Comment: Good observations. Obviously I didn't look at the down clues enough. (I only didi it in the top middle part.) Speaking of rot13(vapbzcyrgr f'f be znlor f—'f, sbhe bs gur ynfg svir qbja pyhrf zvtug nyfb dhnyvsl.),

Comment: Oh, "rot13(vapbzcyrgr jbeqf fgnegvat jvgu F)"? Maaaaybe, I guess. There are also, of course, some rot13(Ff vzzrqvngryl orsber gur grne gung nera'g vapbzcyrgr gurzfryirf).

Comment: The rubric seems really underdetermined. I guess the two unclued Down entries rot13("gryy lbh ubj gb trg guvatf onpx gb abezny") or something like that. I suspect something important is lurking within "The last characters (repl... characters)" -- rot13("ercynpvat", vg jbhyq frrz, ohg jung arrqf ercynpvat urer?) And there must be some significance to rot13(gur snpg gung gur ynfg yvar bs gur ehoevp vf erq jura abguvat ryfr vf) but I fear that despite what Deusovi _says_ some knowledge of the relevant cultural artefacts would be illuminating.

Comment: Regarding the Down clues, btw, although I think you found the intended ones anyway there are definitely useful hints in 27d, 31d, 33d, 34d, and for 33 and 34 at least I needed those in order to have any confidence that I'd completed them as intended.

Comment: The title might be rot13(Bbcf! Nyy Npebff Gur Obneq) which rot13(unf 9 yrggref nsgre gur vapbzcyrgr FF) but unfortunately rot13(FGUROBNEQ qbrfa'g frrz gb or nalguvat hfrshy, rira vs nantenzzrq).

Comment: Hm. I don't hope that we are really looking for rot13("vapbzcyrgr e'f", orpnhfr pyhr sbegl unf whfg "vagre" erzbirq naq "snprf" vf gur svefg-yrggre vaqvpngbe. Vagre-snpr vf pbairavragyl ulcurangrq naq gur grkg genafpevcgvba ercyvpngrf gung.)

Comment: Perhaps that even extends to rot13(e–, orpnhfr gur npghny tylcu hfrq va gur CQS naq va gur grkg vf na ra qnfu.)

Comment: Ooooh, nice observation. I had thought earlier that rot13(gur yvaroernxf jrer yvxryl gb or fvtavsvpnag, tvira gung Qrhfbiv unq gnxra pner gb cerfreir gurz va gur grkg irefvba), but had completely forgotten :-).

Comment: If it's rot13(vapbzcyrgr [qnfu]f) or something like that, then it does give something for the apparent "rot13(ercynpvat)" to apply to, maybe. Though I'm still not seeing quite how it works.

Comment: The other thing that seems worth noting is that it says rot13(n ybpngvba) not rot13(ybpngvbaf) which suggests that we're looking for just rot13(bar cynpr ba gur cntr) rather than e.g. rot13(jung unccraf nsgre rirel grne va n jbeq fgnegvat jvgu F be rirel jbeq va gur pebffjbeq gung pbhyq or pbzcyrgrq).

Comment: A few hints for the last step: [1] You haven't used the "(repl [...] characters)" part of the instruction; this ([rot13](http://rot13.com))(eryngrf gb gur guerr-yrggre zrffntr lbh unq whfg rkgenpgrq.) [2] Once that's resolved, you'll need to look at something that ([rot13](http://rot13.com))(lbh pbhyq abg trg sebz gur genafpevcg - gur vzntr be cqs vf nofbyhgryl erdhverq.)

Comment: Clink! (That may have been the sound of a penny that has dropped. Let me check.)

Comment: Of course, I utterly retract my suggestion that there was an error in 40a. (As I rather expected to have to.)

Comment: Yes, you've found everything! ([rot13](http://rot13.com))(ERGERNGRQ vf n cha ba "ena njnl" naq "tnir sbbq gb [gur thrfg / gur cebgntbavfg] ntnva". GHEA BIRE N ARJ YRNS vf whfg n cha ba ubj gur gbea cntr zvtug or svkrq - "trg n arj furrg bs cncre"). The "discovery" is the same plot-relevant "gruesome discovery" mentioned in part 1, not a thing for you in particular to discover.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I thought that rot13("er-gerngrq" jbhyq creuncf or na nantenz vaqvpngbe, ohg V unq ab vqrn jung sbe.)